# How can I prevent a background image from being cut-off when viewed on a phone or when the viewport size is decreased?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The following happens to my background image when viewed on a mobile device. How can I resize or crop it, without changing the image, so that it covers the entire page.

[image]

Comment: Could be wrong but do you mean `background-size: cover` (if you are using `background-image`

Comment: background-image: url(../img/brain.jpeg);

Answer (score 3):

You will have to implement `background-size: cover;` for desktop and an optimized background-image for mobile and tablet using media queries. (Create individual images - one to use for desktop, one for mobile, one for tablet)

Unfortunately, `background-size:cover` tends to break and dissapear on mobiles and iOS devices!

Your code will look something like this for a bulletproof design (adjust your custom height, etc..):

```
section {
    background-image: url(section-bg-mobile.jpg);
    background-position: center center;    
    height: 500px;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    section {
        background-image: url(section-bg.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        min-height: 725px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS you want to use:

```
.background-element {
   background-image: url("http://wherever.com/your-img.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center; /* or 50% 50% */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

**`background-size: cover`** will expand the image to fill its container and **background-position: center** will, well, *center* it.

Of course, this will require that the element, of which your image is the background, to be 100% of the viewport width and height.

```
.background-element {
   background-image: url("http://wherever.com/your-img.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center; /* or 50% 50% */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

   position: fixed;
   z-index: -1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
 }
```

or

```
.background-element {
   background-image: url("http://wherever.com/your-img.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center; /* or 50% 50% */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   /* or height: 100vh; */
 }
```

depending on whether your element is a child of the `body` element or the `body` element itself, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

you can use bootstrap framework for the same.
 To link the bootstrap freamework use the following code.

```html
<head>
  
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  
</head>
```

After this in the body section to re-size the background image you can use according to the size of your mobile device img-responsive class.
Follow the below code snippet to achieve the same.

```
<body>
    <img src=".." alt="background-Img" class="img-responsive">
</body>
```